# Eclipse: How to Create "Linked Resource" not in .projects Directory?

Tags: eclipse

I am using the Eclipse RCP for Developers to create a version of the Workbench that's specialized to the development we do at work. Most of this has already been done, but I am fine-tuning now.

To initialize a project, users have to create a "preferences" file, which contains various settings. These settings include the "paths" for the code/files they want the project to load. Until now, users have had to nest all relevant code/files in the directory that contains the preferences file, like so:

./folder/file.prefs
./folder/nestedFolder/
./folder/nestedFolder2

(And so on.)

However, I'd like for users to be able to provide relative paths for folders/files not in the home directory, like so:

../../randomFolder/

The only problem I've seen (this works fine for integrating the code/file itself) is getting it to "show up" in the package explorer tool. To do this, you have to create a linked resource (as I already wrote code to do, for nested directories).

However, when I try to link to non-nested folders, I get this error:

```
ResourceException: Could not created linked resource {path}. Parent resource not accessible.
```

My code looks like this:

```
for (String path: FolderPaths) {
   IFolder folder = project.getFolder(path)
   if (!folder.exists()) {
      folder.createLink(pathBase.append(path), IResource.FOLDER, nullProgressMonitor)
   }
}
```

"pathBase" is an "IPath" pointing to the home directory's full-path.

Note that even if the FolderPath "path" is relative to the original prefs file:

```
 ../test/folder
```

Creating an IFolder with the "project.getFolder(path)" method changes it to:

```
 /test/folder
```

Presumably, this is because the "workspace" is now attempting to create a project folder in the local directory, then link that folder to the path I pass in; this has always worked in the past, but now I get the error above.

Comment: Note: `IResource.FOLDER` is not a valid value for the `updateFlags` parameter of `createLink`.

Comment: Thanks! Originally, it was IResource.NONE (as designed by the first developer), but unfortunately this ran into the same error.